# How to make Compose component non-focusable?

Tags: kotlin, focus, compose-desktop

I have a Composable Row that has some click listeners:

```
val action = { ... }
Row(Modifier.clickable(action) {
  IconButton({ /* other, unrelated action */}) {}
  Text("This isn't clickable")
  Checkbox({ /* something that calls action() on toggle */ })
}
```

When tabbing through this UI, the focus goes to the IconButton, then the Checkbox, then the Row. I want it to skip the row. I've implemented that by adding to the Row modifier:

```
val manager = LocalFocusManager.current
Row(Modifier.clickable(action).onFocusChanged { 
  if (it.isFocused) manager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next) 
}) { /* same content */ }
```

... which works when moving forward, but not when moving backward (using Shift-Tab). And of course that's because of the `FocusDirection.Next`, which should instead be `Previous` when moving backward. But how do I detect that? The focus event doesn't have a direction property.

**Update**
I tried doing this by manually detecting if shift is pressed, which feels more like a hack than a solution:

```
val keys = LocalWindowInfo.current.keyboardModifiers
/* in onFocusChanged */
manager.moveFocus(if (keys.isShiftPressed) FocusDirection.Previous else FocusDirection.Next)
```

.. and also, it doesn't work. Calling `manager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Previous)` if shift is pressed causes an infinite loop and application crash, presumably because it's setting the focus back to where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Modifier.focusProperties { canFocus = false }` should help you!

An example of usage:

```kotlin
Row(Modifier.focusProperties { canFocus = false }.clickable(onClick = action)) {
  IconButton({ action() }) {
    Text("IconButton")
  }
  Text("This isn't clickable")
  Button(onClick = { action() }) {
    Text("Button")
  }
}
```